# Solving a constrained optimization problem using Lagrange Multiplier

Tags: optimization, lagrange-multiplier, quadratic-programming

I am trying to solve a relatively simple single variable constrained quadratic programming but having hard time. The problem is as follows:
$$
\min_x ax^2-b(1+x)
$$
subject to
$$
0\leq x \leq1
$$
$$
b(1+x)-ax^2>c
$$
$a,b,c>0$. I tried to use Lagrange Multipliers ($\lambda_1, \lambda_2$ for two constraints) but couldn't make sense of the first order condition.
Any guidance would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Lagrangian can be written as

$$
L(x,y,\lambda_1,\lambda_2,\lambda_2,s_1,s_2) = y + \lambda_1(x(1-x)-s_1^2)+\lambda_2(-y-c-s_2^2)+\lambda_3(a x^2-b(1+x)-y)
$$

Here $s_1,s_2$  are slack variables used to transform two inequalities into equations. The stationary conditions furnishes us

$$
\nabla L = 0 = \left\{
\begin{array}{l}
\lambda_3 (2 a x-b)+\lambda_1 (1-2 x) \\
 -\lambda_2-\lambda_3+1 \\
 (1-x) x-s_1^2 \\
 c + y +s_2^2\\
 a x^2-b (x+1)-y \\
 \lambda_1 s_1 \\
 \lambda_2 s_2 \\
\end{array}
\right.
$$

Now solving those equations we will know the stationary points and also the solution.

Comment: Is $y$ objective function? I don't quite understand $\lambda_2 (y-s_2^2)$ part.

Comment: Now it is fixed.

Comment: I believe the last expression in the RHS should be $\lambda_3 (ax^2-b(1+x)-y)$, correct? The way I formulated Lagrangian was $L(x, \lambda_1, \lambda_2, s_1, s_2)=ax^2-b(1+x)+\lambda_1(x(1-x)-s_1^2)+\lambda_2(b(1+x)-ax^2-c-s_2^2))$, what is the difference between my formulation and your formulation? I couldn't understand why we are introducing more variables here.

Comment: No difference at all. It is a matter of style.

Comment: I see. Thank you for your response. It helped me a lot.